# Four Keyboard - Where am I wrong?

Tags: algorithm, dynamic-programming

I'm learning dynamic programming, and I have a question of a 4-keyboard. It states the following:

> Imagine you have a special keyboard with the following keys:
>
> Key 1: (A): Print one 'A' on screen.
>
> Key 2: (Ctrl-A): Select the whole screen.
>
> Key 3: (Ctrl-C): Copy selection to buffer.
>
> Key 4: (Ctrl-V): Print buffer on screen appending it after what has already been printed.
>
> Now, you can only press the keyboard for N times (with the above four keys), find out the maximum numbers of 'A' you can print on screen.

I came up with the following thought. Let `f(n)` be the max 'A' I can type for `n` time key press, than I have the following:

`F(n)=max{f(n - 1) + 1, f(n - 1) + buffer, f(n - 3) * 2`

For `f(n - 1) + 1`, it simply means press 'A'.

For `f(n - 1) + buffer`, it means press `ctrl-v` so the number of 'A's in buffer will be added to the screen.

For `f(n - 3) * 2`, it means performing `ctrl-A`, `ctrl-c`, `ctrl-v`.

I have the following observations:

`key    0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8
MaxA   0 1 2 3 4 5 6 9 12
buffer 0 0 0 0 0 0 3 3 3`

When I tried to calculate `f(9)` based on my thought, it should be 15. But the answer is 16.

Can anyone point out where my transition function is incorrect? Thanks a lot.

Comment: I understand `f(9)` should be select-all, copy, paste, paste, paste from step 5. But I'm wondering where I am wrong.

Comment: For 9, 111123444 gives 16. Btw, I guess your function should have two arguments, both `n` (time left) and `buffer` length.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that the number of `A`s in your `buffer` should be a parameter of your `f`, i.e, `f(n, buffer_size)`, because if you only use `f(n - 3) * 2` without maintaining `buffer_size`, you are implicitly modifying the `buffer`.